# AS to PHP (decodeToByteArray, encodeByteArray)

Tags: php, actionscript-3, base64

```
message = "this is the message";
key = "the_key";
timestamp = "20130121";
this_id = "13291";

key = Base64.decodeToByteArray(key);
message = this_id + "-" + timestamp;
hmac = Crypto.getHMAC("sha1");
message = Hex.fromArray(hmac.compute(key, Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(message)))) + "-" + message;
data = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(message));
gen_token = Base64.encodeByteArray(data);
```

I do not know AS but I need to convert the above AS function to PHP. Are there any similar functions in php which is similar to "decodeToByteArray" and "encodeByteArray"? I am only able to do the following.

```
key = base64_decode(key);
$message = $this_id ."-".$timestamp;
$message = hash_hmac ('sha1', $key , $message) . $message;
$gen_token = base64_encode(key);
```

Comment: Doing a quick search for some of that actionscript shows that some of it is from the library [twitterscript](http://code.google.com/p/twitterscript/source/browse/trunk/src/com/dynamicflash/util/Base64.as?r=12) for anyone wondering.

Comment: Also, OP, perhaps you could ask a more specific question instead of asking for us to translate the code for you?

Comment: Why is `message` overwritten with `this_id + '-' + timestamp`? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string **base64_encode** ( string *$data* )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

```
string **base64_decode** ( string *$data* [, bool *$strict = false* ] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

ByteArray (array of 8-bit entities) is, in effect, a string.

So, **base64_encode** and **base64_decode** do all what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the code doesn't make sense, such as this:

```
message = this_id + "-" + timestamp;
```

That would overwrite the value of `"this is the message"`.

Also, it seems to generate a keyed hash over just an id and timestamp, leaving the message contents vulnerable to unwanted changes. What would make more sense is that you calculate the keyed hash over `this_id`, `timestamp` **and** `message`.

```
$key = base64_decode('value of key expressed in base64 string');
// calculate signature for remote validation
$sig = hmac_hash('sha1', "$this_id-$timestamp-$message", $key);

$gen_token = base64_encode("$sig-$message");
```